# Junkware and permission to redistribute modified versions

Tags: licensing, bundling

[This article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2938017/why-big-open-source-projects-are-fleeing-sourceforges-free-software-hub.html) describes a problem with a particular online software hub:

> The download-hosting site retreated after public outcry, removing the junkware it inserted into downloads of the popular GIMP image editing tool without the developers’ permission.

In this case it was "public outcry" that caused this behaviour to stop. Are there any open source licences that preclude such behaviour? Is there a way of licensing that prevents legally adding junkware to software and then offering it for download?

Does this depend on whether it is claimed to be the original software, and whether it uses any protected trademarks?

Comment: If your software is registered as a trademark, you can prevent other people from distributing their products (even if they are modified versions of your own product) under your trademark name. This is why Firefox is called "Iceweasel" in Debian. GIMP does *not* seem to be a registered trademark, though.

Answer (score 3):

If the "junkware" was licensed as the license required, including it may not have been nice. But it was a legal thing to do.

Any license that would prohibit any form of modification or usage would not be a Free Software or Open Source license.

**Edit:**

A license which specifically prohibits adding bundled 3rd party software with a commercial goal would not be a Free Software or Open Source license.

Comment: *"Any license that would prohibit any form of modification or usage would not be a Free Software or Open Source license."* -> Okay; but this is not what was asked for. What was asked for is a license which specifically prohibits adding bundled 3rd party software with a commercial goal.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: So... the right answer concludes that this question is not on-topic? Can we just assume, that the Open-Source license is implicit on this site? Or I edit it in.